# When do we need to consider Quantum electrodynamic density functional theory?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-optics, density-functional-theory

We know well quantum electrodynamics (QED) and density functional theory (DFT). The former describes the quantum nature of electromagnetic field, and the latter typically concerns the quantum and many-body system of electrons. In recent years we witness the emergence of a theory combining QED and DFT or even time-dependent DFT. Regarding the regimes when the theories are required, it is clear for QED and DFT. My question is when we need this new combined theory. Is there a quantity which can serve as an indicator?

Thanks!

Comment: i suggest to post this question at https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com

Comment: If the question is solely about DFT, I consent mattermodeling is more suitable.